how to create a new json file for each run of the Spring Batch application instead of overwriting the existing one
@Component
public class FirstItemWriter {
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss");
String timestamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());

String path = "C:\\Workspace\\AutoDialer\\CmeAutoDialerJson_" + timestamp + ".json";

@StepScope
@Bean
public JsonFileItemWriter<Long> jsonFileItemWriter() {
    
    
    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource=new FileSystemResource(path);
    
    JsonFileItemWriter<Long> jsonFileItemWriter = new JsonFileItemWriter<>(fileSystemResource,
            new JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller<Long>());

    return jsonFileItemWriter;
}

}
@Service
public class SecondJobScheduler {
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Qualifier("secondJob")
@Autowired
Job chunkJob;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?")
public void secondJobStarter() {
    Map<String, JobParameter> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("currentTime", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(params);
    
    try {
        JobExecution jobExecution = 
                jobLauncher.run(chunkJob, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Job Execution ID = " + jobExecution.getId());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while starting job");
    }
}

}
I have created a spring batch application which runs every 2 minutes it creating a json file josn_2024_04_29_222936 but in the second run instead of creating new json it was editing the old json file how to create a new json file in the second batch run.

What I believe is happening is that the timestamp variable gets defined when your service starts up. Meaning it happens only once and every job after that will have the same timestamp value meaning the file name will be the same.
Instead define a new timestamp AND path variable inside the jsonFileItemWriter method.
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss");


@StepScope
@Bean
public JsonFileItemWriter<Long> jsonFileItemWriter() {
    // this line will create the unique timestamp each time this runs
    String timestamp = dateFormat.format(new Date()); 

    String path = "C:\\Workspace\\AutoDialer\\CmeAutoDialerJson_" + timestamp + ".json";
    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource=new FileSystemResource(path);
    
    JsonFileItemWriter<Long> jsonFileItemWriter = new JsonFileItemWriter<>(fileSystemResource,
            new JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller<Long>());

    return jsonFileItemWriter;
}


Yeah I have tried by keeping timestamp inside method also but it was not working

Move below variable inside the jsonFileItemWriter() method.
String path = "C:\\Workspace\\AutoDialer\\CmeAutoDialerJson_" + timestamp + ".json";


Yeah i tried but it wasn't worked
